# MySQL: Maximum of date(s) columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 different tables; each have their own DATETIME independent of each other. What would be the MySQL query to get MAX of all dates in 1 query?

```
t1: DATE_TIME
t2: DATE_TIME
t3: DATE_TIME
t4: DATE_TIME
```

Desired result

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| max_t1_date | max_t2_date | max_t3_date | max_t4_date |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to skin this cat...

```
SELECT max( t1.a ) AS max_table1date, 
       max( t2.a ) AS max_table2date, 
       max( t3.a ) AS max_table3date
  FROM table1 t1, 
       table2 t2, 
       table3 t3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used MySQL syntax and I cannot try this at the moment, but this should work:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM t1) AS max_t1_date,
  (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM t2) AS max_t2_date,
  (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM t3) AS max_t3_date,
  (SELECT MAX(date_time) FROM t4) AS max_t4_date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.MaxDate max_t1_date,
  t2.MaxDate max_t2_date,
  t3.MaxDate max_t3_date,
  t4.MaxDate max_t4_date
FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE_TIME) MaxDate  FROM t1) t1
  (SELECT MAX(DATE_TIME) MaxDate  FROM t2) t2,
  (SELECT MAX(DATE_TIME) MaxDate  FROM t3) t3,
  (SELECT MAX(DATE_TIME) MaxDate  FROM t4) t4
```